# Spring Kafka, can I have 2 message consumers with the same topic in the same class (bean)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm implementing social media platform for learning purpose. So basically I have Posts and Comments entities. I want to use the same topic `KafkaTopic.POST` but difference partition `KafkaPartition.POST, KafkaPartition.COMMENT`. I wonder if it will be able to process 2 messages `POST` and `COMMENT` at the same time or not when defining it in the same bean?

```
@Component
public class PostListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostListener.class);
    private final PostService postService;

    private final CommentService commentService;

    public PostListener(PostService postService, CommentService commentService) {
        this.postService = postService;
        this.commentService = commentService;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = KafkaTopic.POST,
                     groupId = KafkaGroup.POST_GROUP,
                     topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = KafkaTopic.POST, partitions = { KafkaPartition.POST })})
    public void on(@Payload PostPayload payload,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) Long timestamp) {

        postService.createPost(payload.getSenderId(), payload.getContent(), timestamp)
                   .subscribe();
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = KafkaTopic.POST,
                     groupId = KafkaGroup.POST_GROUP,
                     topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = KafkaTopic.POST, partitions = { KafkaPartition.COMMENT })})
    public void on(@Payload CommentPayload payload,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) Long timestamp) {

        commentService.createComment(payload.getPostId(), payload.getSenderId(), payload.getContent(), timestamp)
                      .subscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why share a topic between post and comment? Multiplexing them on different partitions seems kinda hacky and not future-proof.

Comment: @Kayaman yeah it's better to separate topic for posts and comments however this is dummy project for learning purpose I'm just curious if I will be able to do this or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can process messages from different partitions of the same topic using Kafka listeners in Spring Kafka. In your case, you have defined two Kafka listeners, each processing messages from different partitions of the same topic (KafkaTopic.POST).

The @KafkaListener annotation allows you to specify both the topic and the partitions from which you want to consume messages. Since you're using different partitions for posts and comments (KafkaPartition.POST and KafkaPartition.COMMENT), your Kafka listeners will be able to process messages concurrently from those partitions.